# MVC and model design - one for each json action? one for each view?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jsonresult

I'm on Microsoft MVC4, I'm starting to have a lot of models and i want to reorganize them.

I'm heavily using jQuery Ajax calls to populate data, thus I have:

- few actions that returns simple views (i.e. empty html tables)
- many actions that return a JsonResult, used to populate tables/listitems and so on

In some action the same element ( 'item' ) is shown with some information( i.e. columns ), in other actions it is shown with other informations.

My two questions:

- should I have a Model for each action that returns a Json Result, for clarity? or i should not bother, and I should use continue using anonymous projection?
- should I have base Models (i.e. the 'simple' ones) and extended models that inherit from base Models? or should i keep the Models sperated, resulting in a cleaner (but less maintenable?) structure?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> should I have a Model for each action that returns a Json Result, for
>   clarity? or i should not bother, and I should use continue using
>   anonymous projection?

Anonymous project is just fine for JSON results. Makes unit testing a bit harder but it's up to you to decide whether you want to introduce a view model here.

> Should I have base Models (i.e. the 'simple' ones) and extended models
>   that inherit from base Models? or should i keep the Models sperated,
>   resulting in a cleaner (but less maintenable?) structure?

You could have inheritance in your view models.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. A 'maybe-silly' question: what is the common practice about models naming? Should a Model be named like the entity that represent ( 'Player' ) or should it be named like the action that generates this model ( 'ListPlayer' ) ? I'm asking this because sometimes the models are a little different, for example for CRUD actions ( Creation model sometimes is different from Update and so on ).

Comment: They could contain the `ViewModel` suffix and be named according to the action.

Comment: Should i use the `ViewModel` suffix even if a model is not directly binded to a View, but instead it is returned by a Json Result? This is why i choosed to call them Models in my questions and not ViewModels ... i was thinking that `ViewModel` is more correct when speaking about a model binded to a View, and simply `Model` when the model it is used as a JsonResult for example (or as a Base model)...  for example: `ListPlayersModel` if returned by a JsonResult action, `UserInfoViewModel` if returned by a ViewResult action ...

Comment: Yes, it should be suffixed by `ViewModel`. In the case of a JsonResult, the *view* representation of your domain model is JSON.